# Why does the shape of my explosion keep changing?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fire

I've been working on a simulating a Hollywood-style fireball. After playing around with Force Fields and whatnot, I've come across with a shape I'm generally happy with. Blender, however, seems hell bent on undoing my work. Everything I do seems to change the simulation.

Scrub through the timeline? Simulation changes. Save the file with a new name? Simulation changes. Pet my cat? Simulation changes. None of these should affect the sim, and yet, they do. This has made further tweaking nigh impossible. What's going on?

Comment: This sort of thing is usually calculated on the fly unless it's baked (which means you can sometimes get inconsistent results). Have you baked the relevant dynamics? Baked systems should replay consistently.

Comment: How does simulation changes if you save file with a different name? Scrabbing the timeline will invoke change of the flames and smoke as they are expected to move with time (the results will be different from only if you changed some options before scrabbing though). Baking the simulation will save results into files but if you scrab the timeline simulation will change in time as well - as it should.

Comment: I've had no issues with baking so far. I'm just wondering why scrubbing through the timeline sometimes changes the dynamics if I leave all the other settings alone. I've also had issues with enabling or disabling Smoke High Resolution radically changing the shape of the explosion. As I understand it, Smoke High Resolution adds detail without changing the dynamics of the sim.

Comment: Is the origin moving on the emitter or model or particle?